# How to return Meta data from the REST API?

Tags: custom-field, rest-api

I added meta box City and Location to my post, but when I calling the endpoint (by WP Rest API) `/wp-json/wp/v2/<post_type>/<post_id>` it's not returning my meta data.

I tried to use **register_meta** like this, but still not working:

```
register_meta('my_post_type', 'city', [
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'Cidade',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true
]);
```

What should I do to return it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The first parameter passed to [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) is always `post` *for posts, Pages (post type of `page`) and custom post types*.**

However, the REST API Handbook [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field-vs-register_meta) that:

> Prior WordPress 4.9.8, meta fields set to `show_in_rest` using
>   `register_meta` are registered for all objects of a given type. If one
>   custom post type shows a meta field, all custom post types will show
>   that meta field. As of WordPress 4.9.8 it’s possible to use
>   `register_meta` with the `object_subtype` argument that allows one to
>   reduce the usage of the meta key to a **particular post type**.

So this should work:

```
register_meta('post', 'city', [
    'object_subtype' => 'my_post_type', // Limit to a post type.
    'type'           => 'string',
    'description'    => 'Cidade',
    'single'         => true,
    'show_in_rest'   => true,
]);
```

But then, the REST API Handbook also [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#read-and-write-a-post-meta-field-in-post-responses):

> Note that for meta fields registered on custom post types, the post
>   type must have `custom-fields` support. Otherwise the meta fields will
>   not appear in the REST API.

So make certain that your post type has support for `custom-fields`:

```
register_post_type(
    'my_post_type',
    array(
        'supports' => array( 'custom-fields', ... ), // custom-fields is required
        ...
    )
);
```

### Alternate Solution

This one uses [`register_rest_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) and you can easily use `my_post_type` in the code. But this is of course a *simplified example* and you should check the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field) for more information:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field( 'my_post_type', 'city', array(
        'get_callback' => function( $post_arr ) {
            return get_post_meta( $post_arr['id'], 'city', true );
        },
    ) );
} );
```

Also, the metadata will not be *in* `meta`, but instead in the top-level just as the `meta` property. Sample response body/string: (just part of the full response)

- With `register_meta()`: `,"meta":{"city":"London"},`
- With `register_rest_field()`: `,"meta":[],"city":"London",`

Comment: It's still not returning the meta field

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: That's great! actually I'm using the `Alternate Solution` for now, but then I'm wondering if it's the correct way, because it's basically doing a new request to the database, as I know, is it going to impact the performance if I have a massive requests?

Comment: Metadata requests (using the WordPress API/functions) are cached, and actually, even with the non `Alternate Solution`, WordPress also performs the same request, except it [uses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_meta_fields/get_value/#source) `get_metadata()` directly and not `get_post_meta()` which is a wrapper to `get_metadata()` for post meta. And the reason to why I added the alternate solution is in case your post type can't/don't have support for `custom-fields`. I hope these helps you, even if not much.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it really helped me

Comment: You're welcome and all the best!