# Create custom post with meta field with AJAX and the Wordpress REST API

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

I have created a custom post type and I got it to show in the REST API. 
I have also registered a custom field using the following code :

```
function slug_get_post_meta_cb( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name );
}

function slug_update_post_meta_cb( $value, $object, $field_name ) {
    return update_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name, $value );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
 register_rest_field( 'custom_type',
    'myfield',
    array(
       'get_callback'    => 'slug_get_post_meta_cb',
       'update_callback' => 'slug_update_post_meta_cb',
       'schema'          => array(
           'type' => 'string',
           'context' => array( 'view', 'edit' )
       ),
    )
 );
```

I'm using jQuery to create an ajax POST request in order to create a new custom post with the following javascript code :

```
jQuery.ajax( {
                    url: requete.api,
                    method: 'POST',
                    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', questionnaireScript.nonce );
                    },
                    data:{
                        title : myData.title,
                        content: myData.content,
                        status: "publish",
                        myfield: "Stop flying"
                    }
                } ).done( function ( response ) {
                    console.log( response );
                } );
```

The posts are created all right, by without the custom field `myfield` . It does show up as part of the custom post object in the response to a GET request, but as an empty array. I also tried to set it as `myfield : ["Stop flying"]`, and as `meta : {myfield: "Stop flying"}`,  to no avail.
I am aware of the other WP function to register a meta field (`register_meta`). However since the documentation reads that it cannot be applied to a custom post type only I chose to use register_rest_field instead.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but here the `$object` is an object and not array:

```php
// Here, $object is a WP_Post object.
function slug_update_post_meta_cb( $value, $object, $field_name ) {
    return update_post_meta( $object->ID, $field_name, $value );
}
```

And you can actually use [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) with a custom post type:

```php
register_meta( 'post', 'myfield', [
    'object_subtype' => 'custom_type', // Limit to a post type.
    'type'           => 'string',
    'description'    => 'My Field',
    'single'         => true,
    'show_in_rest'   => true,
] );
```

Check my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331834) for more details.

Comment: I tried replacing all the php code I posted above by register_meta, but now I don't even see the custom field in the objects I get in the GET response. Do you know why ?

Comment: Also, I see that the argument "object_subtype isn't listed in the documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta

Comment: That's an outdated doc. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) for an updated one. Also, did you read everything [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331834)? Make sure your custom post type supports custom fields.

Comment: But with your original code in the question, you could just try to use `$object->ID` instead of `$object['id']` in the `slug_update_post_meta_cb()`.

Comment: Yes I did, and my custom post type supports those : 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'custom-fields'. I'm very confused.

Comment: Can you update the question with your new code (PHP & JS)?

Comment: I tried again with a full stomach, and a walk outside, with the fix you proposed to my original code, and it works ! Thank you very much, that was very helpful.

Comment: See.. you were just starving I guess. :p Anyway, I'm glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and JSON.stringify() your data as you pass it over, and send it over as that type:

```
// Data to pass over
obj_to_pass = {
  title : myData.title,
  content: myData.content,
  status: "publish",
  myfield: "Stop flying"
};
```

```
// Updated AJAX call
jQuery.ajax( {
  url: requete.api,
  method: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', questionnaireScript.nonce );
  },
  dataType : 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(obj_to_pass)
} ).done( function ( response ) {
  console.log( response );
} );
```

I felt like I have had issues with it in the past. I don't have a good testing environment to test it in, so fingers crossed!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It doens't work, unfortunately. There must be something else going wrong.

Comment: It turns out it had nothing to do with my JS code, but there was a mistake on the php side.